# How to pass values from a middleware to a route in Express.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

```js
const router = require('express').Router()
const loggerMiddleware = (req, res, next) => {
  console.log(`${req.method} ${req.path}`)
  req.locals.isLogged = true
  next()
}

router.get('/color', loggerMiddleware, (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.locals.isLogged)
  res.send('#ff0000');
})
```

When I run the code above, Node compiler gives me a warning of `TypeError: Cannot set property 'isLogged' of undefined`. Where do I go wrong?

Comment: first check if `req.locals` is defined, and if not, define it as `{}`

Comment: Try like  this.  req['locals']['isLogged'] = true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put locals to `res` not `req`

```
const router = require('express').Router()
const loggerMiddleware = (req, res, next) => {
  console.log(`${req.method} ${req.path}`)
  res.locals.isLogged = true
  next()
}

router.get('/color', loggerMiddleware, (req, res) => {
  console.log(res.locals.isLogged)
  res.send('#ff0000');
})
```

Answer (score -1):

I am not familiar with how to pass data from a middleware to a route, but this looks like a plain javascript issue. It looks like `req.locals` is undefined. Start by checking if `req.locals` is undefined. If it is undefined, intialize it through `req.locals = {}`. Then set `req.locals.isLogged = true`.